# SQLite tools for Windows Phone 8 (Viewing data in tables)

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am heavily using SQLite in my Windows Phone 8 app and I was wondering if you have any good tools that would allow me to see what data is inserted/sorted in SQLite?

https://isostorespy.codeplex.com/ only works with isostorage data, so its no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SQLiteStudio from  http://sqlitestudio.pl/. Its simple and quick.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Firefox add-on [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)

I intend to try out a new tool on [codeplex](https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/123666) which supposedly has VS integration, it's a relatively new tool.